# Why flag declined for the post?

Tags: discussion

Today i flagged one post as Too Broad.

[Change address of the customer confirming shipment](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241071/change-address-of-the-customer-confirming-shipment)

I flagged this. Because, this post not include the magento version. So that, i flagged this. Please check once.

Answer (score 4):

This is why: https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/close/136147

Comment: Is it possible to find reviews for specific questions/answer? (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/magento-2-code-migration-installation-using-git/120274#120274 ... its not an answer and was posted as question later)

Comment: @sv3n Maybe look through the review history...I don't know.